# Pulling elements out of a session array deletes the whole array in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, session-variables

I am trying to store an array of values in a session variable.

So when I am trying to add a variable I simply do:

```
$request->session()->push('some.array', $id);
```

When I am trying to pull it out, I do:

```
$request->session()->pull('some.array', $id);
```

I can add as many number of elements using the push method but when I try to pull it, it deletes the whole array. How to go around this problem. How to delete only the element with a specific id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the docs you will see that

```
$request->session()->push('some.array', $id);
```

if actually creating a sub array on session called [array] so when you `pull` using

```
$request->session()->pull('some.array');
```

you are in fact instructing laravel to delete the whole sub array.

So to just delete just a single member of `some.array` you will have to

```
print_r( $request->session()->all() );

$tarray = $request->session()->pull('some.array');
unset( $tarray['an_item'] );
$request->session()->push('some.array', $tarray);

print_r( $request->session()->all() );
```

Comment: But that will only get the item, right? I want to remove the particular item.

Comment: I have changed my answer

Comment: I think this should work. I thought there will be a method in the codebase to do it already. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Yea I cannot say that Laravels session management is particularly elegant in this area

Comment: I almost forgot to accept this answer. Thank you for the help. :)